# Why are multiple points showing in this gganimate plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

So I am trying to plot this data using gganimate:

```
YEAR WEEK COUNTRY CODE    MARKET          ARRIVALS   DATE        pct.chg
2020    1   Usa   US     CONTAINER SHIPS    347    2020-01-08    7.7639752
2020    2   Usa   US     CONTAINER SHIPS    395    2020-01-15   -2.2277228
2020    3   Usa   US     CONTAINER SHIPS    353    2020-01-22   -15.1442308
2020    4   Usa   US     CONTAINER SHIPS    359    2020-01-29   -11.3580247
2020    5   Usa   US     CONTAINER SHIPS    385    2020-02-05    0.2604167
```

The data is in an object called changesimp. I want to plot the arrivals over time, as you might expect. So here is the code I'm using to do that:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)    
changesimp %>% 
      filter(COUNTRY == "Usa") %>% 
      filter(YEAR == "2020") %>% 
      ggplot(aes(DATE, pct.chg)) +
      geom_line() +
      geom_point()+
      labs(y="Year-over-year % change",
           x="",
           title="Percent change in port calls")+
      theme_clean()+
      transition_reveal(DATE)
```

This worked fine when I was just using geom_line. But when I added the geom_point part then things got a little weird and it give me this output (this is just one frame from the animation):

[image]

What I'm trying to get is something like this, [found here](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/287-smooth-animation-with-tweenr.html):
[image]

There is only one value of pct.chg per week, I have checked already. So I'm not sure why it is plotting multiple points like this. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I use dummy data as

```
df <- data.frame(
  COUNTRY = c(rep("Usa",26)),
  YEAR = c(rep("2020",26)),
  WEEK = c(1:26),
  pct.chg = c(rnorm(26,0,15))
)

changesimp <- df %>%  mutate(DATE=(7*WEEK+as.Date('2020-01-01', format="%Y-%m-%d")))
```

Your program works fine and generates the following output:

[image: output]